# Bash: split on delimiter but keep the delimiter

Tags: bash, split, delimiter, ifs

I would like to split a String into an array using delimiters and keep those delimiters.
I tried using IFS but it re,oves the delimiters.

For example:

```
ligne="this.is/just(an]example"
IFS='}|//|)|(| |{|[|]|.|;|/"|,' read -ra ADDR <<< "$ligne"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
   echo $i
done
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
this
.
is
/
just
(
an
]
example
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `bash` isn't really intended for this level of data processing; whatever features it has are typically meant for simple filename manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `grep` with `-o` option:

```
grep -oE '[^][^./(){};:,"]+|[][^./(){};:,"]' <<< "$ligne"
```

```
this
.
is
/
just
(
an
]
example
```

Regex in use is alternation based with 2 alternations:

- `[^][^./(){};:,"]+`: Match 1+ of any character that is not in character class
- `|`: OR
- `[][^./(){};:,"]`: Match any character that is in the character class

Comment: OP might want to remove the `+` from the second alternation, empty fields are often represented by consecutive delimiters, in which case it would be better to match every delimiter as a separate occurence rather than regroup them. As a side note I'm very surprised your character classes aren't broken by the unescaped `]`. Is it because neither `[]` nor `[^]` would be valid character classes?

Comment: @Aaron If you want `]` in your bracket expression, it has to be the first character, optionally preceded by `^` for a negated class.

Comment: @Aaron: Good point on not using quantifier `+` for 2nd alternation (edited).

Answer (score 0):

There is no trivial solution to this with Bash builtins as far as I know, but if that's what you need, you could do something like this.

```
ligne="this.is/just(an]example"
array=()
while true; do
    for delim in '}' '//' ')' '(' ' ' '{' '[' ']' '.' ';' '/"' ','; do
        frag=${ligne#*"$delim"}
        [ "$frag" = "$ligne" ] || break
    done
    [ "$frag = "$ligne" ] && break
    head=${ligne%"$frag"}
    array+=("${head%"$delim"}" "$delim")
    ligne=$frag
done
```